# How do you extend a NativeScript plugin without "re-writing" it?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to modify the camera icon in an iOS image picker. There is NativeScript plugin for that called [nativescript-mediafilepicker](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker). But, it does not expose any APIs to change the camera icon.

I know that most NativeScript plugins are just a "wrapper" around native APIs. In this case, the plugin is a wrapper around the [DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController) Pod.

Now, I thought I could simply access the picker, see where the `UIImage` was being created, and then override the method and put my own UIImage as output. Yet, in the source code [the picker controller is not even exposed](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker/blob/4a3c38ecb06e0483ec49001727bc790e71c0ebf5/src/mediafilepicker.ios.ts#L158).

My question is, for situations like this, is creating my own NativeScript plugin my only option?

Here I want to leverage the whole functionality of the plugin, but I want to extend it by modifying the camera icon. How can I do that without rewriting the plugin or depending on the plugin author in NativeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to make a fork of the plugin repository, add the functionality you need and then build and publish your version so you can use it.